React native npx expo run:android
I dont understand what is going on, I got this error when trying to run npx expo run:android
I have checked my firewall and nothing is wrong and I have updated all dependencies, packages
please help,[ the complete error log is in the image below, it says network timeout at: https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-bare-minimum/-/expo-template-bare-minimum-51.0.27.tgz
] Thanks(https://i.sstatic.net/vVELj3o7.png)
I tried to check if native directory was created but none was created, I also updated all dependencies, packages and checked firewall but is not blocking the network

Try use npx expo start then press I for iOS and a for android.
I case you want to use config plugins run npx expo rebuild before  run npx expo run:android

This is what it brings when I run npx expo prebuild or npx expo run:android
network timeout at: https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-bare-minimum/-/expo-template-bare-minimum-51.0.27.tgz
× Failed to create the native directory
You may want to delete the ./ios and/or ./android directories before trying again.

Did you really need to create a custom build ? If not create an app as follows: npx create-expo-app StickerSmash --template blank and run the app with npx expo start.
To run the app focus the terminal and press i (iOS) or a (android) that should start the emulator/simulator

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

did you find a solution for this ? I am running this same issue for a week or so where I am unable to make it run with that specific command.
